# How to Import All method of Custom Js file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I just start learning Angular and Now I want to convert a template into Angular 
and for this, I need to import template's custom js
After a little search, I do not find any solution related to importing "ALL" function of custom js file into my .component.ts file at once

I already tried to use 
declare const with my specific js method name

```
declare const myTest: any; 
onClick(){
   myTest();
 }
```

I just want to import all method of custom.js file at once

Comment: is `custom.js` is in your app source  , another npm pakage or it online how did you add the js file to your project 

Comment: `declare const myTest: any; ` just tell typescript there is a variable even if it not loaded on exist (not loaded )

Comment: yes in src/assets/js/custom.js

Answer (score 0):

"Answering" b/c my rep isn't high enough to add a comment to ask, but are you getting specific errors with an import statement?

```js
import * as myTest from 'path/to/custom/file';

//or

const myTest = require('path/to/custom/file');
```

Comment: not an error but I just want to call js from my component to external js 

it works only when I pass specific method name into .component file but I just want to add all method from my thousands line js file once

Comment: Either one of the examples above *should* give you access to the methods/properties defined in your custom.js file: `myTest` becomes an object containing all of it (e.g., `myTest.method1(params)`,  `myTest.property5`, etc.).